# Bootstrap Lighbox - how to add caption with link?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gallery, bootstrap-lightbox

I would like some of my Lightbox gallery images to have a caption with a link to another website. And if the caption link can open up in a new window/tab like the `target="_blank"` style. But I have no idea how to do this. Could I have some help please? Thanks in advance :)

Code for one gallery image:

```
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3  bottom-space"> 
    <a href="img/photos/gallery/gallery_photo044.jpg" data-lightbox="tristone" data-title="My caption goes here">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/photos/gallery-thumbs/gallery-thumbs044.jpg">
    </a> 
</li>
```

I have read somewhere I could use data attributes, so I tried data-href:

```
<li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3  bottom-space"> 
    <a href="img/photos/gallery/gallery_photo044.jpg" data-lightbox="tristone" data-title="My caption goes here" data-href="http://mylinkgoeshere">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/photos/gallery-thumbs/gallery-thumbs044.jpg">  
    </a> 
</li>
```

But of course that didn't work since I don't really know what data-href does so I was just guessing :( I did look up about it but I guess my coding level isn't good enough so I don't understand it ^^;

Lightbox.css:

```
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url(../img/close.png) url(../img/loading.gif) url(../img/prev.png) url(../img/next.png);
  display: none;
}

.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}

.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat;
}

.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}

.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}

.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url(../img/prev.png) left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url(../img/next.png) right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}

.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../img/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a file location inside a `href`?

Comment: The example I found had the data-href tag inside, so I just followed: (http://jsfiddle.net/vxy2hdaw/2/) I'm hoping there is a way to add a link to the caption without any javascripts or extra coding. Is data-href tags the right way to go or it is more complicated? If it's too complicated I may have to think up of an alternative way to present my information. Thank you!